# Un-assign Keyboard Shortcut to Chrome Add-on (xyz)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I had a very nice add-on xyz installed on chrome. Somewhere somehow a window showed up that let me assign keyboard shortcuts to enabling disabling my current add-ons. I wanted to get rid of that window and hit Ctrl-W. This shortcut was assigned to xyz addon, and I closed the window immediately! Then, I go looking for shortcut settings for add-on and I am unable to find it. now I am unable to close the tabs at all using that key combination(instead it toggles enable/disable that add-on keeping the current tab open), nor am I able to locate that shortcut corner. Can somebody locate it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, go to `chrome://extensions` then on the bottom right of that page, click the link `Keyboard shortcuts`.

I believe this is the window you're describing, that stole `ctrl-w` from you:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

(I must say the gui-window for shortcuts very well hidden). The Only way I could get rid of this problem was by uninstalling and re-installing the addon - xyz, which rebound the keystroke Ctrl+W to the action close tab.